# Multitouch Android - Using Half the Screen for One finger and Half for the other

Tags: android, multi-touch

Hi im making a split screen game and i cannot figure out how to get the controls down. Right now they work fine if only one person is touching the screen but once multiple do the first person to touch is the only one who can control. So i need to implement multitouch. I cant figure out how to do it so once one finger is down controlling the object on the top half of the screen another finger can be put down controlling the bottom half of the screen. How should i do this?

EDIT:
I changed it, it still doesnt work though could somebody tell me why

My attempt that doesnt work:

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      //needs multitouch
      if(checkInGame()){

                if(event.getY() < this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2){  
                    pointerId1 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
                }else{
                    pointerId2 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());    
                }

                switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{

                        if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId1){  
                            Log.d("Touch","Move1");
                              int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                          int moveX = 0;
                          int moveY = 0;
                          moveX = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex) - sX;
                          moveY = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex) - sY;

                          ship1.setLoc(moveX, moveY);
                          sX = sX + moveX;
                          sY = sY + moveY;
                        }else if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId2){
                              int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                            Log.d("Touch","Move2");
                              int moveX = 0;
                              int moveY = 0;
                              moveX = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex) - sX2;
                              moveY = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex) - sY2;

                              ship2.setLoc(moveX, moveY);
                              sX2 = sX2 + moveX;
                              sY2 = sY2 + moveY;
                        }
                          return true;


                    }
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                            if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId1){
                                Log.d("Touch","Top1");
                                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                                sX = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                                sY = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                            }else if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId2){
                                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                                Log.d("Touch","Bottom1");
                                 sX2 = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                                 sY2 = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:{
                            if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId1){
                                Log.d("Touch","Top2");
                                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                                sX = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                                sY = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                            }else if(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) == pointerId2){
                                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
                                Log.d("Touch","Bottom2");
                                 sX2 = (int) event.getX(pointerIndex);
                                 sY2 = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
                            }
                            return true;
                      }


                }
```

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to track each pointer by its ID. On pointer down, check the ID so you know that pointer with ID 1 is controlling object 1. Give this Android blog post a read, it may help: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: ive read it a couple times i dont really understand it though like how do pointer id's stay constant throughout multiple touches

Comment: Say if you had one finger down it might have index 0 and ID 0. Than you add another finger and it becomes index 1 and ID 1. Then if you remove the first finger, the second finger becomes index 0 but its ID remains 1. The system somehow keeps track of each finger for you. What logcat outputs are you getting?

Comment: The problem is with `getActionIndex()`. The method only works for ACTION_POINTER_UP or ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, otherwise it will just return the first pointer as this is ACTION_MOVE. You can still get the x and y for each pointer using `MotionEvent.getX(int pointerIndex)`.